# Next.js Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string - while trying to use Next.js with MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to use Next.js with MUI v5 and in order to do so I had to make some configurations to remove server-side injected CSS and fix the resolution order. I used [this tutorial](https://dev.to/hajhosein/nextjs-mui-v5-tutorial-2k35) and followed every step. but when I run the script `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` I face this error:
[image: Error Description]
What should I do to fix this problem?

Here's my _document.js file:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import createEmotionServer from '@emotion/server/create-instance'
import createEmotionCache from '../src/utility/createEmotionCache'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <link
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
                    />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage
    const cache = createEmotionCache()
    const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache)

    /* eslint-disable */
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
            enhanceApp: (App) =>
                function EnhanceApp(props) {
                    return <App emotionCache={cache} {...props} />
                },
        })
    /* eslint-enable */

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html)
    const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
        <style
            data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(' ')}`}
            key={style.key}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
        />
    ))

    return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: [
            ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
            ...emotionStyleTags,
        ],
    }
}
```

And here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "testing-next-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.0",
    "next": "12.0.10",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to run this on stackblitz, only change was to create a key for emoticon cache - https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-qda1h3?file=pages%2F_document.js - I never encountered your error.

Comment: @Ramakay Do you think the problem can be originated another file?

Comment: Its possible, what route were you checking ?

Comment: @Ramakay The application was single-paged. I was trying to test some MUI components in index.js but I encountered this error.

Comment: The issue is most likely in another file. Make sure you're importing/exporting React components (your own and third-party ones) correctly across your codebase.